# How to test a retun value fom a private class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, list

I have a class where I return a list, how do I pass the retun Value in a testclass. Currently I get the error Variable does not exist: lstRet

```
 public static String getPicklistData(String objectName,String fieldName){        
            ...    
            List<picklistData> lstRet = new List<picklistData>();        
            for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
            {picklistData obj = new picklistData();
             obj.val = f.getLabel();
             lstRet.add(obj);
            } 
            return JSON.serialize(lstRet);
        }
```

Test

```
static testMethod void test1() { 
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'testM1', Type ='Option1'); 
        insert acc;    
        picklistController.getPicklistData(String.valueOf(acc), String.valueOf(acc.Type) );
        System.assertEquals( 'string', lstRet); 
    }
```

Comment: You are not creating the variable `lstRet` in test class. Nothing to do with `private` here. You can call the method in test class like this: `List<picklistData> lstRet = picklistController.getPicklistData(String.valueOf(acc), String.valueOf(acc.Type) );
        System.assertEquals( 'string', lstRet); `

Comment: @HemantJain  I tried your solution but get Invalid type: picklistData

Comment: Is picklistData a inner class? If yes, can you try referring it as `OuterClass.InnerClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

split method into parts, use [private](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm) access modifier in combination with [@testVisible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm) annotation

```
public static String getPicklistData(String objectName,String fieldName){        
    ...    
    List<picklistData> = getLstRet(ple); 
    return JSON.serialize(lstRet);
}

@testVisible
private static List<picklistData> getLstRet(List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple){
    List<picklistData> lstRet = new List<picklistData>();        
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
        {picklistData obj = new picklistData();
        obj.val = f.getLabel();
        lstRet.add(obj);
    }
    return lstRet;
}
```

test class would like like:

```
static testMethod void test1() { 
    Account acc = new Account(Name = 'testM1', Type ='Option1'); 
    insert acc;
    Test.StartTest();
        List<picklistData> actual = picklistController.getLstRet(param); //param is List<Schema.PicklistEntry> type
    Test.stopTest();
    List<picklistData> expected = new List<picklistData>(); //init expected values
    System.assertEquals(expected, actual); 
}
```